# If hibernat.hbm2ddl.auto is having value create with MYSQL then hibernate not able to create schema

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to generate mysql schema automatically when I run a hibernate program with spring but it giving below exception

It is working properly with DERBY DB but it is giving problem with MYSQL

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'hdb'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 41 more
```

For which I have done below configuration

app.properties file

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hdb
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=java
jdbc.initialSize=1
jdbc.maxActive=2
```

spring.xml file

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbc.initialSize}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="${jdbc.maxActive}" />
    </bean>


   <bean id="namedParameterDaoImpl" class="org.net.dao.NamedParameterDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>app.properties</value>
        </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>org.net.model</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>
```

So I am not able to understand why it is not working.

Comment: There is a difference between name of connection and name of Database,try for example 'h' (without db) or other .. 
Did you do that ?

Comment: same issue I am getting for new name

Comment: It will not create the database, it will only create the tables. The database already has to be there. Derby has a default schema (especially when used in memory) hence the database already exists and tables can be created.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, for your reply.

Comment: Now its working :)